# Java - Verify PKCS7 signature using sun classes

Tags: java, security, encryption, digital-signature, pkcs#7

How to verify PKCS7 signature using `sun` classes? I know that it is bad thing to do, but for some reasons I can't use BouncyCastle of any other external libraries.

I can get the content from PKCS7 using the following code:

```
str = str.replace("-----BEGIN PKCS7-----\n", "").replace("-----END PKCS7-----", "");
PKCS7 pkcs7 = new PKCS7(Base64.decodeBase64(str.getBytes("UTF-8")));
byte[] b = new byte[pkcs7.getContentInfo().getContent().getData().available()];
pkcs7.getContentInfo().getContent().getData().getBytes(b);
String s = new String(b, "UTF-8");
return s.substring(s.indexOf("<")); //there are some strange symbols before <?xml
```

But I need to verify signature first. Of course I have a certificate to do this:
`private X509Certificate certVerify;`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to write a CMS and underlying ASN.1 BER/DER library yourself. Sun doesn't contain any official API to handle the CMS messages specified by PKCS#7 (or the followup RFC's).

---

The JRE may contain useful code in the *implementation* of Java. Note that these classes are *not* part of the API and may change over different versions of Sun's / Oracle's Java. Furthermore, they may not be present *at all* in 3<sup>rd</sup> party implementations of Java.

```
import sun.security.util.*;
import sun.security.x509.AlgorithmId;
import sun.security.x509.X500Name;
import sun.security.x509.KeyUsageExtension;
import sun.security.x509.PKIXExtensions;
import sun.misc.HexDumpEncoder;
```

These API's *should not* be used. They even cannot be used without making an change in the access conditions of the runtime in e.g. Eclipse.

---

Note that the Bouncy Castle libraries have a *very* permissive license; you could even copy the source code to your application (as long as you leave the initial statement in there, *read the license* for more details). If your employer tells you that you cannot use even that then there might be something seriously wrong in the organization.

Comment: But I found the working code that creates signed PKCS7 here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/13910/pkcs7-encoding-in-java-without-external-libs-like-bouncycastle-etc
It uses only sun classes. Really there's no way to verify the signature?

Comment: I've amended my answer after viewing that code. You could of course pin your Java version (a *very* bad idea for code in general, especially security related code) or use the Sun implementation's GPL license. But it seems to me that Bouncy has advantages over both options.

Comment: >The JRE may contain useful code in the implementation of Java
Yes, these classes I need to use, unfortunately. Do you have an example of using these classes to verify PKCS7 signature? I could not found an example all over the Web

Comment: Even if I had, I would only use them to show how *not* to create a Java application. I'm certainly not going to post code that uses these classes on a public forum. Take control and tell your employer he's not very smart if he doesn't leave implementation decisions like these to his developers. He/she is clearly not up to the job of architect if this is the mandated solution.

Comment: The problem is that we use sun classes to create signed PKCS7 messages, and we use Bouncy Castle 1.40 which can't do it. Bouncy Castle 1.40 could be used to verify the signature, but my teamlead says that it's better to use the same classes to sign and to verify the signature.
If it would be my decision, I'll use BC.
And if we update BC there're some code that breaks because of it. Java version won't be updated in the foreseeable future

Comment: Your team lead should understand that the JCE is a pretty well written API. I don't see why BC classes shouldn't use it. Furthermore, it seems you are not just stuck on a specific Java version but also on an outdated crypto library... for a security related product! Somebody needs to get a clue...fast! Things like this gave Java a bad name in yhe first place, you know installs that include an entire JRE.